# Google Maps freezing on __semwait_signal()

Tags: ios, multithreading, google-maps

I am currently building an app that uses Google maps. Every so often, the app freezes in the main thread on this function, __semwait_signal(), as the superview the google map is in is about to close or navigate away.

Apparently it is an issue that spans multiple programmers.
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6484

I am running the Google Map framework 1.7.2 and testing on an Iphone 4 with iOS 7.1

Can anyone find a work-around for this, or is it something that can only be resolved with the next update on the framework?

Comment: Are you using Annotations? Coz I had faced a similar problem after adding annotations and when I zoom out, the whole app freezes.

Comment: No, I believe it is related to the thread that works out all the labels in the map, like street names, regions, etc.

Comment: did You solve your this problem. If yes, can You please post your solution? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the google map framework is all that it takes to fix this issue.

Check your Framework Search Paths to make sure that the only path to the a Google Maps Framework is the most recent version. I had multiple paths there, which caused other crashing issues as well. https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6672